# Error in sudo update-manager -d while upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

I can't upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 from 17.10. When I run `sudo update-manager -d` it shows an error:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(update-manager:2584): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Before that, `sudo update-manager -d` found the release and was about to start the upgrading process but I cancelled it. And now it's showing that error.

And also, now when I update packages, the PPA sources are Bionic which is from 18.04, not 17.10:

```
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [69.9 kB]
```

As a consequence, after running `apt upgrade`, there are tons of packages to be upgraded which will take 1260 MB.

I know I've messed up everything. How can I upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 in this case? Or can I just upgrade to 18.04 via `dist-upgrade`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you were installing upgrades `sources.list` file was getting updated. After cancelling half of the sources are updated to that of bionic. Try either of the method to troubleshoot it.

Open terminal and type `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` This will list all the sources. The link which have bionic in them just comment it by simply adding `#` in front of it and sources which have artful, uncomment it by removing `#`. Try `apt upgrade` again.

**OR**

Search for the app called as Software and upgrades. In the Ubuntu Software tab change the server and reload. This will edit sources.list and might solve your problem.

For upgrading to 18.04 from 17.10, use `do-release-upgrade`